# Freeing up memory for a dynamic array of array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

Ok , so these are my structures:

```
struct Student
{
    int id;
    char* name;
};

struct HashTable
{
    int size;
    int noElements;
    Student** elements;
};
```

And here I allocate memory for the dynamic array of arrays

```
ht.elements = (Student**)malloc(size*sizeof(Student*));
memset(ht.elements, NULL, size*sizeof(Student*));
```

My question is, when I try to deallocate the memory like this, why does my program crash?

```
for(int i=0;i<ht.size;i++)
{
free(ht.elements[i]->name);
free(ht.elements[i]);
}
free(ht.elements);
```

If I write only the last line it works, but it doesn't generate memory leak?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not valid C.

Comment: @user2079303 So consdier to remove the c tag also ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ good idea! (This might protect the question from a wave of downvotes) @ CanciuCostin, please specify which language you are using.

Comment: @CanciuCostin  You did not show where the memory pointed to by the data member name is allocated and whether it is indeed allocated.

Comment: @CanciuCostin Take into account that to make the program a valid C program you have to write at least struct Student** elements;

Comment: There is no "array of arrays" in your code! A pointer is not an array and cannot be used as one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you're allocating memory for a vector of pointers

```
ht.elements = (Student**)malloc(size*sizeof(Student*));
```

and then you are memseting them to NULL. This means you don't have a matrix of elements, but a vector of pointers to elements that don't point to anything. 
So these line will cause problems

```
free(ht.elements[i]->name) // here you are dereferencing a null pointer, this will cause a segmentation fault
free(ht.elements[i]); // here you are calling free on a null pointer. Depending on your compiler, this could cause problems.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why your programming is crashing:

1. You are accessing `name` in Student objects which do not exist (you've explicitly set the memory to null)
2. You are deallocating `name` when `name` has not been allocated
3. You are deallocating `Student` pointer that have never been initialized

Comment: There is no program in the question. Not even valid C code.